# Is there an alternative to gate drivers like TC4428 or MIC4426 in LTspice?

Tags: mosfet-driver, low-side

I need a dual low-side gate driver but there are just single output N channel drivers in LTspice.
[image]

Comment: A low-side driver is usually a driver that is compatible with an N-channel MOSFET.

Comment: so it can't drive p-channel?

Comment: I've never seen a P-channel MOSFET used in a low-side situation so, to avoid ambiguity you will need to show the schematic.

Comment: I added the picture

Comment: I wouldn't say that the P-channel MOSFETs are in a low-side driver situation; they need to be driven relative to 12 volts from what I can tell.